# save groupBy rdd result back to HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, rdd, thrift

I have some customized thrift-compact based serialization format file on hdfs as input. By extending hadoop's FileInputFormat, we can quickly load the files into a RDD struct.

Now, after applying some groupBy  transformation, the output RDD becomes a `JavaPairRDD<Long, Iterable<thriftGeneratedClass>>`.
Now, I would like to save the groupBy RDD results back to HDFS with multiple output files by the key in the PairRDD. E.X.: if we have two keys-100, 200 in the PairRDD, two files 100.thrift and 200.thrift will be generated. Each file contains all the iterable list of the thrift class. 
code looks like:

```
//Feature is some thrift generated class 
JavaRDD<Feature> featureJavaRDD = jsc.newAPIHadoopFile(inputPath, ThriftInputFormat.class,
            NullWritable.class, Feature.class, jsc.hadoopConfiguration()).values();
JavaPairRDD<Long, Iterable<Feature>> groupByRDD = featureJavaRDD.groupBy(...)
//how to save groupByRDD results back to HDFS with files by key
```

my question is: what's the best way to achieve this?  I know the answer probably involves hadoop `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile` and `MultipleOutputs`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case few days ago,I resolved it in Java by writing two custom classes implemeting `MultipleTextOutputFormat` and `RecordWriter`.

My input was a `JavaPairRDD<String, List<String>>` and I wanted to store it in a file named by its key, with all the lines contained in its value. (So, this is almost the same use case)

Here is the code for my `MultipleTextOutputFormat` implementation

```
class RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat<K, V> extends MultipleTextOutputFormat<K, V> {

    @Override
    protected String generateFileNameForKeyValue(K key, V value, String name) {
        return key.toString(); //The return will be used as file name
    }

    /** The following 4 functions are only for visibility purposes                 
    (they are used in the class MyRecordWriter) **/
    protected String generateLeafFileName(String name) {
        return super.generateLeafFileName(name);
    }

    protected V generateActualValue(K key, V value) {
        return super.generateActualValue(key, value);
    }

    protected String getInputFileBasedOutputFileName(JobConf job,     String name) {
        return super.getInputFileBasedOutputFileName(job, name);
        }

    protected RecordWriter<K, V> getBaseRecordWriter(FileSystem fs, JobConf job, String name, Progressable arg3) throws IOException {
        return super.getBaseRecordWriter(fs, job, name, arg3);
    }

    /** Use my custom RecordWriter **/
    @Override
    RecordWriter<K, V> getRecordWriter(final FileSystem fs, final JobConf job, String name, final Progressable arg3) throws IOException {
    final String myName = this.generateLeafFileName(name);
        return new MyRecordWriter<K, V>(this, fs, job, arg3, myName);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my `RecordWriter` implementation.

```
class MyRecordWriter<K, V> implements RecordWriter<K, V> {

    private RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat<K, V> rddMultipleTextOutputFormat;
    private final FileSystem fs;
    private final JobConf job;
    private final Progressable arg3;
    private String myName;

    TreeMap<String, RecordWriter<K, V>> recordWriters = new TreeMap();

    MyRecordWriter(RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat<K, V> rddMultipleTextOutputFormat, FileSystem fs, JobConf job, Progressable arg3, String myName) {
        this.rddMultipleTextOutputFormat = rddMultipleTextOutputFormat;
        this.fs = fs;
        this.job = job;
        this.arg3 = arg3;
        this.myName = myName;
    }

    @Override
    void write(K key, V value) throws IOException {
        String keyBasedPath = rddMultipleTextOutputFormat.generateFileNameForKeyValue(key, value, myName);
        String finalPath = rddMultipleTextOutputFormat.getInputFileBasedOutputFileName(job, keyBasedPath);
        Object actualValue = rddMultipleTextOutputFormat.generateActualValue(key, value);
        RecordWriter rw = this.recordWriters.get(finalPath);
        if(rw == null) {
            rw = rddMultipleTextOutputFormat.getBaseRecordWriter(fs, job, finalPath, arg3);
            this.recordWriters.put(finalPath, rw);
        }
        List<String> lines = (List<String>) actualValue;
        for (String line : lines) {
            rw.write(null, line);
        }
    }

    @Override
    void close(Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        Iterator keys = this.recordWriters.keySet().iterator();

        while(keys.hasNext()) {
            RecordWriter rw = (RecordWriter)this.recordWriters.get(keys.next());
            rw.close(reporter);
        }

        this.recordWriters.clear();
    }
}
```

Most of the code is exactly the same than in `FileOutputFormat`. The only difference is those few lines

```
List<String> lines = (List<String>) actualValue;
for (String line : lines) {
    rw.write(null, line);
}
```

These lines allowed me to write each line of my input `List<String>` on the file. The first argument of the `write` function is set to `null` in order to avoid writting the key on each line.

To finish, I only need to do this call to write my files

```
javaPairRDD.saveAsHadoopFile(path, String.class, List.class, RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat.class);
```